# How Multiple Forms can Call Same Method on Their Load Event

Tags: c#, forms

I have around 20 forms in my Project of C#. I have created a method in a Class. I want all the 20 forms to call that method in their Load event. I can put the Call statement in the Load Event of each form one by one. However, in future the forms may increase. Also, it may be possible that some form gets missed to write that Call statement in its Load event mistakenly.

Is their any logic, that the specific method can handle the load events of all the forms of the Project? We can get the list of all the forms of the project by using System.Reflection. So, is it possible to attach the load events of all these forms to the same specific method of the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your custom form and override `Onload` (or any event)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public class MyForm : Form
    {
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {                
            MessageBox.Show("test"); //call your method(s)
            base.OnLoad(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and your new form

```
namespace CustomFormProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : MyForm
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             //MessageBox will be shown automatically from your base (MyForm) class
             //other codes
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public partial class Form2 : MainForm
public partial class Form3 : MainForm
...
...
...
public partial class Form19 : MainForm
public partial class Form20 : MainForm
```

Inherit the `MainForm` in your other *Forms* and call the method in their `Form_Load` event.

The `MainForm` is the class in which you've created the method, further which you want to access it in the other forms.

Suppose, the example below is the Method in your `MainForm`.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void Msg()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
}
```

Call the method `Msg()` on the `Form2_Load` event by first inheriting from the `MainForm` class:

```
public partial class Form2 : MainForm
                             ^^^^^^^^
```

Now, call this method:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Msg();
}
```

Similarly, you do the same thing with the rest of your *Forms*.

Comment: This idea of Multi-level inheritance is fine... However, if I have to change the Parent class of each of my Form, then I can also put the Call statement of the method in the Load event of each Form. I actually want to ask that is there any way that I do not change anything in the 20 Forms and my method becomes able to handle the Load events of all the 20 Forms? Please accept my apologies if my question looks stupid...